# Build a Debian package without tarball

Tags: debian, deb

I am trying to build a Debian package for a project I maintain. For this reason, the source tree (which resides in a Git repo) has a subdir called `debian`, with the Debian-related files in it.

However, when I run `debuild -us -uc`, I get the following:

```
This package has a Debian revision number but there does not seem to be
an appropriate original tar file or .orig directory in the parent directory
```

I have tried changing the contents of `source/format` from `3.0 (quilt)` to `3.0 (native)`, still no joy.

How do I prevent the Debian toolchain from insisting on a tarball (given that the source resides in the parent dir of `debian`, not some archive)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If nothing else works, it might help to read the error message properly :-)

The changelog file had a version number of `0.0.1-1`. By Debian conventions, the part after the dash is the Debian revision number. Apparently, when the toolchain encounters this, it concludes that you are debianizing someone else’s package, so there must be an upstream source tree, and demands a tarball.

Changed the version in the changelog from `0.0.1-1` to `0.0.1`, and I got past this error message.